# Commit in nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I created simple test for NHibernate but it not ok. Does anybody know this trouble below.

> identifier of an instance of PosDAL.Users altered from 4
>   (System.Int32) to 0 (System.Int32)

[image: identifier of an instance of Users altered from 4 (System.Int32) to 0 (System.Int32)]

I'm using Sql Server 2008. Users table in db with Id is primary key and auto increase 1. In db, I add simple row like: username, email, fullname, ....etc by hands. Id was 4 . But It was not working. I deleted that row, the program run normal.

My function in BussinessLogic layer:

```
public bool CheckLogin(string sUsername, string sEnCodePassw)
        {
            using(ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
             using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
             {
                 IList oUser = 
                     session
                     .CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE U_USERNAME = ?")
                     .AddEntity(typeof(Users))
                     .SetString(0, sUsername)
                     .List();
                 tx.Commit();
                 return false;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a transaction for a select and needless to say that you don't need to commit anything because you are not modifying any data. So, try getting rid of the transaction...

```
using(ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
         {
             IList oUser = 
                 session
                 .CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE U_USERNAME = ?")
                 .AddEntity(typeof(Users))
                 .SetString(0, sUsername)
                 .List();
             return false;
         }
```

Also make sure your code logic actually does what it should do. Currently your code will always return false, you should change the return statement to something like this...

```
return oUser != null && oUser.Count > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation.
I have another ideas but it's return false:
<br/>
`return oUser.Contains(sEnCodePassw);`
<br/>

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Cool...I didn't notice you edited your first comment by asking a question

Comment: Here is my solved:

**I change**
- IList oUser = ...List() ;

**to**

`IList<Users> oUser = .....List<Users>();`<br/>
`User oObject = new User(); `<br/>
`oObject = oUser[0];`<br/>
`return (oObject != null && oObject.Password = sEncodePassw);`<br/>